# ID from list that is not in a table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with a primary key `id` let's call it staff table and it contains the following ids: 1,2,3,5,7

And I also have a list of staff ids separated by comma, e.g. 1,2,3,4,5,6

How do I write an SQL (mysql) that can check which ids from the list that are not in the table (e.g. 4 and 6)

I tried to search around and most of the results always around `NOT IN` but this is not what I want as

```
select * from staffs where id not in (1,2,3,4,5,6)
```

will return me 7 which is NOT what I want, I want 4 and 6

Also I'm not in favor of creating any temporary tables

Thanks

Comment: where is the list '1..6' coming from?

Comment: it's adhoc so the list is not from a database. Basically someone just give me a list of ids to check if they are in the database, and let him know which ones are not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would this work?

```
SELECT
   listOfIds.id
FROM
    (      SELECT 1 AS id
     UNION SELECT 2
     UNION SELECT 3
     UNION SELECT 4
     UNION SELECT 5
     UNION SELECT 6) listOfIds
LEFT OUTER JOIN staff
ON listOfIds.id = staff.id
WHERE staff.id IS NULL
```

Try this [example in SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/adb81/1).

Comment: Thanks it works, though in reality I have thousands of non-sequential (and possibly duplicated) ids to check. I was kinda hoping there will be easier answer. I'll wait for a bit before accepting this

Comment: I agree that it's an ugly solution, @Don Djoe. I'm also interested to see if someone has a more elegant solution that works with 'select only' permissions.

Comment: Do it in a loop in n application script

Comment: Yeah, I guess I could do it by writing an application script but it'll take time so it's not really what I'm after. I'm quite amazed that MySQL doesn't really have a simple solution for a "simple" problem like this. The requestor was actually standing behind me and we thought we could get the answer in a few minutes ...

Comment: I need the same thing. Simple solution is to `select * where id in (list)`, and then subtract the result from the original list. But that seems so heavy-handed when the sql server should be able to do that.